# Missing reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

Yesterday, stats.SE showed I had a rep of 503. Today, it shows I have a rep of 501. The missing 2 points are not listed in my activity anywhere.

Furthermore, meta.stats.SE still indicates that I have a rep of 503.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Reputation changed unexpectedly? Don't know where to turn? [We've moved heaven and earth to ensure your score is always correct!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes)

Per the system message currently showing at the top of the page, we have performed a global recalc of everyone's reputation.  As a result of the new changes, your rep will be in sync.

Check out your [reputation history](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1977/jeff?tab=reputation) for October 1, 2011.  You had a post that was deleted and the rep change came from that.  This is now visible in your reputation report and going forward will be less confusing.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link! However, the post on Oct 1 wasn't actually mine, it was someone else's, and I got +2 for editing it. It seems kind of weird that I should lose that rep-- doesn't that mean I could lower the rep of thousands of people all at once by deleting my own account? Anyone who's ever posted a response suddenly loses credit? Not really a big deal, I just thought it a strange system...

Comment: Yes, when a post is deleted, the reputation goes with it.